# Cv joint with less than 5 miles but looks ground up

Tags: cv-joint

I installed a new cv joint drove less than 5 miles realizing I was sold a bad axel I pulled the new one out and it is ground where it goes into the transmission. Any idea what would cause this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing that would cause that is the output bearing on your transmission being seized.  You should be able to inspect it by sticking your finger in the opening and seeing if you can rotate it.  My guess is that it's either totally seized or is so badly damaged that it's nearly that way.

You can see the scoring and galling on the shaft from the friction.

Comment: Thank you, I've never dealt with this sorta issue but I will definitely check that out

Comment: You didn't forget to refill the transmission with fluid did you?

Comment: No the fluid in the transmission is full

Comment: On some vehicles the differential oil is separate from transmission fluid. While you're checking the bearing like @jwh20 said, stick your finger further and see if there's fluid/gear oil.

Comment: I asked that because on many vehicles, the fluid runs out when you pull a half-shaft out.

Comment: I appreciate the help and I did do that when I was inspecting it and there is fluid in there